# Argument of type 'By' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ProtractorBy | WebElement'

Tags: typescript, protractor

I am trying to learn protractor and I have a project setup that has this code:

```
var elementToWaitFor = by.id(controlIdToWaitFor);
browser.wait(x=> browser.isElementPresent(elementToWaitFor));
```

This gives the typescript error of:

> Argument of type 'By' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ProtractorBy | WebElement'

However, I if I do this:

```
var elementToWaitFor = $('#' + controlIdToWaitFor);
browser.wait(x=> browser.isElementPresent(elementToWaitFor));
```

The error goes away.

I thought those where supposed to be the same.  I am guessing I am hitting a protractor vs selenium issue, but I am not sure what the fix is.

Note: My typescript file has this at the top (in case it is relevant):

```
import {browser, element, by, By, $, $$, ExpectedConditions, protractor} from 'protractor';
```

Comment: You need to use 'by' with 'element' - element(by.id(....)) With the $ sign you are using a short form for the css by locator. http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the same:

```
var elementToWaitFor = element(by.id(controlIdToWaitFor));
var elementToWaitFor = $('#' + controlIdToWaitFor);
```